# Get the difference (hours) from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours(d1.getHours() +01);
alert(d2);
```

This part is ok. Now i'm trying to put a string inside `(d1.getHours() +01);` $string instead of +01. Like this:

```
<select id="timezone-select">
<option value='-02:00'>GMT -02:00</option>
<option value='-01:00'>GMT -01:00</option>
<option value='+00:00'>GMT +00:00</option>
<option selected='' value='+01:00'>GMT +01:00</option>
<option value='+02:00'>GMT +02:00</option>
</select>

var str = document.getElementById('timezone-select').value;
var res = str.substr(0, 3);
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours(d1.getHours() res);
alert(d2);
```

Any help please?

Comment: It would make life easire if you implemented the value as minutes, e.g. "+120" instead of "+02:00" so that you can easily accommodate any time zone offset.Of course you can still display "+02;00" as the text. Also, there doesn't seem to be a good reason for creating two date objects, why not `var d1 = new Date(); d1.setMinutes(d1.getMinutes() + parseInt(document.getElementById('timezone-select').value));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `d2.setHours(d1.getHours() res)` to `d2.setHours(d1.getHours()+parseInt(res))`